# How to specify google play services dependency in maven

Tags: android, maven, google-play-services

I build a project with maven, I want to add a dependency to Google play services wear. My Gradle build file has

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
```

and in my pom.xml under "dependencies" I put

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
  <version>5</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

but maven keeps complaining "Could not find artifact".
How do I specify the dependency of google play services wear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Google-Developers:

> In versions of Google Play services prior to 6.5, you had to compile the entire package of APIs into your app. In some cases, doing so made it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536 limit.
>
> From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play
>   service APIs into your app.

So, try to replace the "version" in you pom.xml to 6.5 or above

Comment: I now have 
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-play-services-wearable</artifactId>
   <version>7.5</version>
   <type>aar</type>
  </dependency>
but I still get 

"Could not resolve dependencies for project org.roboguice:roboguice:jar:3.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.google.android.gms:google-play-services-wearable:aar:7.5 in third.party.closed.source.repo"

Comment: I think the 64k limit isn't that important as gradle has multi-dex? multi-dex support is what made me switch from Eclipse to Android Studio.

Comment: mvn is looking in maven_repo_3rd_party, but the jars are in the .m2 repo. hmm.

Comment: I found out how the project expects android jars to be pre-loaded in a repo dir. Now it builds.